# Haskell Typeclasses : What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Brand new to Haskell and trying to write a parser.

I've used attoparsec to successfully chop my input file up into tokens into an AST.

I now want to walk the AST and emit output from it. I thought I could do that by adding some generic routines to Token class by deriving from a type class and then providing specific functions where needed in an instance to emit code based on the Token type.

The code is probably easier to follow than my explanation. This is what I tried:

```
class AST a where
  children :: a -> [a]
  prefix :: a -> String
  suffix :: a -> String
  node :: a -> [String]

  children v = []
  prefix v = ""
  suffix v = ""
  node v = [prefix v] ++ (concatMap node $ children v) ++ [suffix v]

data Token =  Line { lnName :: String, lnLines :: Int }
            | LineList { llLines :: [Token] }
            | Init String
            | Main String
            | Step { stId :: String, stDuration :: Float }
            | Scene { scId :: String, scTokens :: [Token] }
            | Sequence { sqId :: String , sqScenes :: [Token] }
            | File {flContents :: [Token]} deriving (Show, AST)
```

So my understanding is that if I derive from the type class I've written that:

- I don't need to provide an instance definition as all of the functions have default implementations
- I can override the defaults per Token type if needed

But I get an error from ghc that's not all that helpful

> Parser.hs|27 col 60 error|  Can't make a derived instance of `AST Token':`AST' is not a derivable class In the data declaration for `Token'

Fair enough, but why is that the case? Kind of at a loss as to how to fix it without any more information. Any help gratefully received.

I know this isn't a useful comment but I have to say, absolutely loving Haskell. It's been a joy to learn :)

Comment: Beware. A Haskell type class is something quite different from a class in the average OO language. `deriving` is only a helper to make some instances that are always trivial (but nasty, because so widespread) even simpler to define, nothing else; the general way remains `instance`. — In your case, I wonder whether you should use a type class at all – perhaps just another `data` would be better.

Comment: By the way, there's absolutely no advantage to using a type class in this context. What other instances are there? What rules do all the instances follow such that you can reason about the bounded polymorphism? If you want polymorphism here, throw a type variable  on the `Token` type and use parametric polymorphism instead.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comments. I already implemented the code gen as individual type overloaded functions. The down side is I end up with a bit of boilerplate I don't want and so I'm trying the typeclass way with default functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`deriving` can be use for a [limited, fixed list of typeclass](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Classes_and_types#Deriving). The problem here is that you need to tell the compiler that the function you have defined are an instance of class `AST` for the datatype `Token`, like so:

```
class AST a where
  children :: a -> [a]
  prefix :: a -> String
  suffix :: a -> String
  node :: a -> [String]

instance AST Token where
  children v = []
  prefix v = ""
  suffix v = ""
  node v = [prefix v] ++ (concatMap node $ children v) ++ [suffix v]

data Token =  Line { lnName :: String, lnLines :: Int }
            | LineList { llLines :: [Token] }
            | Init String
            | Main String
            | Step { stId :: String, stDuration :: Float }
            | Scene { scId :: String, scTokens :: [Token] }
            | Sequence { sqId :: String , sqScenes :: [Token] }
            | File {flContents :: [Token]}
            deriving (Show)
```

Comment: Ah I see. That's a shame and feels a bit hacky. I'd hoped that if you created a type class that supplied all default functionality you could add it to your deriving list, I didn't realise that it was a fixed list :(

Comment: It's not hacky. As explained in the question comments, typeclasses are useful when you will have a lot of different instances, usually not trivial. `deriving` is useful because the compiler now how to *derive* instance (adapt them to the specific data). In your example, there is nothing to derive.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean your solution but that Haskell only allows predefined classes in the deriving clause. Reading your link they actually make the same point. The conclusion is fair enough though :D 

> This provision of special "magic" function synthesis for a limited set of predefined classes goes against the general Haskell philosophy that "built in things are not special". However it does save a lot of typing. Experimental work with Template Haskell is looking at how this magic (or something like it) can be extended to all classes.

Comment: No offense. There are actually extension that allows you to derive other typeclasses: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/users_guide/deriving.html Anyway, you should really consider if typeclass is the appropriate approach in your case.

Comment: I'm new to this so all of this is great for me. I'll explain my thinking. This way I can seperate some concerns. The parser and Token don't need to know anything about the AST type class and I can put my specific code generation into a separate file. I also want to have more than one type of code generation so it seemed that this would be a good way to achieve that, say a binary output and a text one. I'm assuming that I can have > 1 instances of AST with the same type if I make them private in a file :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Nicolas' explanation that deriving is only applicable to a specific set of typeclasses I've fixed my problem. My solution is slightly different from Nicolas's in that I can still retain generic functionality in AST rather than tie it to Token

```
class AST a where
  children :: a -> [a]
  prefix :: a -> String
  suffix :: a -> String
  node :: a -> [String]

  children _ = []
  prefix _ = ""
  suffix _ = ""
  node v = [prefix v] ++ (concatMap node $ children v) ++ [suffix v]

data Token =  Line { lnName :: String, lnLines :: Int }
            | LineList { llLines :: [Token] }
            | Init String
            | Main String
            | Step { stId :: String, stDuration :: Float }
            | Scene { scId :: String, scTokens :: [Token] }
            | Sequence { sqId :: String , sqScenes :: [Token] }
            | File {flContents :: [Token]} deriving (Show )

instance AST token where
  -- per token overides added here
  -- defaults run if none supplied
```

Thanks everyone